# Bourne shell - make a loop for each element in an array?

Tags: arrays, loops, sh

This is my array:

```
ListTabs=""
ListTabs=$ListTabs"T_Tab1\n"
ListTabs=$ListTabs"T_Tab2\n"
ListTabs=$ListTabs"T_Tab3"   
echo $ListTabs
arrArr=0
OLD_IFS=$IFS;
IFS=\n
for listArr in ${ListTabs[@]}; 
do 
     #echo $listArr
     MYDIR[${ARR}]=$listArr
     (( arrIdx = $ARR+ 1 ))
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS;
```

then, i have done a sort of id from a select in this way (FILESELECT_DAT is a output file of query):

```
sort -u ${FILESELECT_DAT} > ${SORT_OUT1}
```

ok..Now i have to make a loop that for each element of array makes a SELECT where ID = values of ${SORT_OUT1}. So there are 2 loops. A while on ID and a for loop for the select. How can i loop the ID inside ${SORT_OUT1}? I think this is the begin

```
id=""
while read $id
do
for ListTabs in ${listArr}
do 
-
-
SELECT * FROM $ListTabs(but the results is alway the first tab in each loop)
WHERE ID = ${id}(but he show me all IDs)
-
-
done < ${SORT_OUT1}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `ListTabs` is not an array. It's a string. The entire first block of code can be replaced with `listArr=( T_Tab{1,2,3} )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listArr=( T_Tab{1,2,3} )
sort -u "$FILESELECT_DAT" > "$SORT_OUT1"
while read id; do
    for ListTabs in "${listArr[@]}"; do
     ...
    done
done < "$SORT_OUT1"
```

Take care that nothing in the body of the `for`-loop reads from standard input, or it will consume part of the input intended for the `read` command. To be safe, use a separate file descriptor:

```
while read -u 3 id; do
...
done 3< "$SORT_OUT1"
```

Comment: It's a bourn shell so it's the only way i think to make an array. Your solution get an error.. Even in "done 3< "$SORT_OUT1". the output is :  3: This is not an identifier.

Comment: You tagged the question as `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry but i use both bash and sh and i confuse them. Howevery, is sh.