# Unix shell - read array content in a for loop

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop, ksh

this is my array:

```
orlist=""
orlist="T_TAB1 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB2 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB3 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB4 \n"
echo $orlist
arrIdx=0
OLD_IFS=$IFS;
IFS="\n"
for IndixList in ${orlist[@]};
do
     echo $IndxList
     MYDIR[${arraryIndix}]=$IndixList
    (( arraryIndix = $arraryIndix+ 1 ))
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

i have to do a SELECT in a oracle db inside a for loop so i have to read the $orlist tab by tab. I've tried this but doesn't work it takes the whole array not tab by tab:

```
for arraryIndix in ${orlist[@]};
do

  echo "SET HEADING OFF"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TERMOUT OFF"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET PAGESIZE 0"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET LINESIZE 1000"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET FEEDBACK OFF"      >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TRIMSPOOL ON"      >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SPOOL ${FILE_DAT}"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SELECT * "             >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "FROM ${orlist[@]}"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "WHERE REP_ARG = 2; "   >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SPOOL OFF"             >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "COMMIT;"               >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET HEADING ON"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TERMOUT ON"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET PAGESIZE 14"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET FEEDBACK ON"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TRIMSPOOL OFF"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "EXIT;"                 >> ${FILEOR_SQL}

  sqlplus -S -L ${Connection} @${FILEOR_SQL} #connection is a var for connect with `sqlplus`

done
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: How come you're not using actual arrays?

Comment: in wich sense?sorry i don't understand your question

Comment: In the sense of an actual array. `var=("element 1" "element 2")`

Comment: and then?for the loop?

Comment: however i've got an error: Syntax error at line 101 : `(' is not expected.

Comment: Are you using a shell that supports actual arrays?

Comment: ksh..i don't think support actual arrays. Is there another way?

Comment: `ksh` does support arrays (and better than `bash`), but your implementation/version might not support the `foo=(...)` notation.

Comment: As you can see the only problem now is the IFS :(

Comment: If your shell supports the `(( ... ))` arithmetic expression, it almost certainly supports arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bourn shell - make a loop for each element in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566483/bourn-shell-make-a-loop-for-each-element-in-an-array)

Comment: Now the only problem for me is the OLD_IFS doesn't recognize because i have a oracle error: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied . The sqlplus conncetion is correct! 100% sure iv'e made a function as has suggested abasu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your problem came because if you write `\n`, it's not necessarily treated as a new line, somebody have to translate the sequence of `\` followed by `n` as a newline. also same in `IFS="\n"` IFS needs to be set to something which evaluates to a newline, not a combination of `\` and `n`. Also orlist is a variable, you have not used it as an array, and at the for loop, it is not going to be treated as an array.
I did some changes and it seemed to work fine

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ksh
orlist=""
orlist="T_TAB1 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB2 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB3 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB4 \n"
echo  $orlist
arrIdx=0
OLD_IFS=$IFS;
IFS=$'\n'
#IFS=""
arraryIndix=0
for IndxList in `echo -e $orlist`
do
     echo "Hello $IndxList "
     MYDIR[${arraryIndix}]=$IndxList
    ((arraryIndix++))
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
echo "Finally ${MYDIR[@]}"
```

Output

```
T_TAB1 \nT_TAB2 \nT_TAB3 \nT_TAB4 \n
Hello T_TAB1
Hello T_TAB2
Hello T_TAB3
Hello T_TAB4
Finally T_TAB1  T_TAB2  T_TAB3  T_TAB4


$ ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-02-02
```

Update following comments

```
FILEOR_SQL=""
func() {
  echo "SET HEADING OFF"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TERMOUT OFF"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET PAGESIZE 0"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET LINESIZE 1000"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET FEEDBACK OFF"      >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TRIMSPOOL ON"      >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SPOOL random     "     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SELECT * "             >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "FROM $1"               >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "WHERE REP_ARG = 2; "   >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SPOOL OFF"             >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "COMMIT;"               >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET HEADING ON"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TERMOUT ON"        >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET PAGESIZE 14"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET FEEDBACK ON"       >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "SET TRIMSPOOL OFF"     >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
  echo "EXIT;"
}
orlist=""
orlist="T_TAB1 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB2 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB3 \n"
orlist=$orlist"T_TAB4 \n"
echo  $orlist
OLD_IFS=$IFS;
IFS=$'\n'
arraryIndix=0;
for IndxList in `echo -e $orlist`
do
  FILEOR_SQL="testfilesql"$arraryIndix
  func $IndxList
  ((arraryIndix++))
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Comment: Are you sure that this way goes with ksh? Because i have Syntax errors

Comment: mmh ok done. Now my list is a list line by line.. For the for loop? How can i do it?

Comment: I checked in ksh, seems to be working same, Sorry, i did not understand `list is a list line by line`

Comment: yes, but before my outpu was : T_TAB1 \nT_TAB2 \nT_TAB3 \nT_TAB4 \n only and not line by line :). The problem is the loop.. Seems the loop doesn't recognize the newline.. it stamp me in the output sql file the whole array: FROM T_TAB1 \nT_TAB2 \nT_TAB3 \nT_TAB4 \n ando not fro the first cicle FROM TAB1 for the second FROM TAB2 etc etc.. understand?

Comment: ahh, mean the 2nd loop? here first iteration should create a file with `FROM T_TAB1`, second one `FROM T_TAB2` right? then you already have the array prepared in `MYDIR`, instead of `for arraryIndix in ${orlist[@]};` use `for arraryIndix in ${MYDIR[@]};`.

Comment: i think should be make something like a counter in the loop.. like: ${MYDIR[@]}+1 but i don't know how EDIT:trying your suggestion

Comment: I should warn you, in the second for loop, `arraryIndix` will contain the individual element while iterating, you have used `echo "FROM ${orlist[@]}" `

Comment: Well i looked at both the scripts, and to each their own style. But still, i think, when you are doing something repeatedly, you always should write a function so that maintainability becomes easier. So updated with some modification and combined both the scripts

Comment: Nothing :( the output of the sql file is this one:                 `SET TERMOUT ON`
`SET PAGESIZE 14`
`SET FEEDBACK ON`
`SET TRIMSPOOL OFF`
`EXIT;`
`SET HEADING OFF`
`SET TERMOUT OFF`
`SET PAGESIZE 0`
`SET LINESIZE 1000`
`SET FEEDBACK OFF`
`SET TRIMSPOOL ON`
`SPOOL FIle.dat`
`SELECT * `
`FROM T_TAB1`
`T_TAB2`
`T_TAB3`
`T_TAB4` EDIT: i've seen now your update..i try now.

Comment: i have an error in ((arrayIndix++)) ... i think this (( arrIdx = $arrIdx + 1 )) is correct.

Comment: Arrrrgh!! ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: The problem is the IFS now. You helped me a lot and your way is correct :D now 6 loops and every loop a different tab. The only problem is the oracle error and i think the IFS is the problem :'(

Comment: Well, if you have restored the IFS, it should not cause a problem, sadly I don't have any knowledge about oracle. Otherwise, you might try to call the oracle api from a different script. when we invoke a script, it gets executed in a subshell. So in parent shell, IFS remains untouched. This way, even if some change happened, next script will be a different subshell, so you can verify if current script is causing any damage to that oracle api call

Comment: I think is the IFS because 2 days ago i had the same problem. I resolved adding the OLD_IFS that i had forgotten. But here there is already!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking sqlplus many times, make the SQL script contain all the queries:

```
cat < END1 > ${FILEOR_SQL}
SET HEADING OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SPOOL ${FILE_DAT}
END1

orlist=(T_TAB1 T_TAB2 T_TAB3 T_TAB4)

for table in "${orlist[@]}"; do
    echo "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE REP_ARG = 2;" >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
done

echo "QUIT" >> ${FILEOR_SQL}
sqlplus -S -L ${Connection} @${FILEOR_SQL}
```